# Passing parameter to PageRenderer Prism Xamarin Forms

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, prism

I am trying to create authentication process using Xamarin Form and Prism.
I created *PageRenderer* class for each platform and i need to pass custom parameter to it. Tried to use *INavigationAware* interface in ViewModel and then access it from custom page but *OnNavigatedTo* method invoked after *PageRenderer* initiated, so navigation parameter still empty.

Can anyone suggest a solution for this problem?

Comment: Just so you know, you can also add the INavigationAware interface to the Page itself. I have never tried doing what you are doing, but see if that helps at all.

Comment: Same behavior as before. I don't want to break MVVM because of that.

Comment: Without a sample or some more information it's hard to understand what your issue is. 
1) You understand the process 6.3.0 process goes `OnNavigatingTo` -> Push new Page -> `OnNavigatedFrom` -> `OnNavigatedTo` (6.2 doesn't have `OnNavigatingTo`
2) Is there a reason you can handle the parameter after the PageRenderer is initiated?

Comment: I just need pass parameter to PageRenderer with Prism

Answer (score 2):

There are a few ways you could handle this:

1) As suggested make the page INavigationAware and set the property you want to access from the PageRenderer. Depending on what it is that you're sending this could of course break the MVVM pattern. But you could do something like follows:

Create an interface

```
public interface IMyPage
{
    string Message { get; set; }
}
```

Setup your ViewModel to handle the parameter you need to send to the Renderer

```
public class MainPageViewModel : BindableBase, INavigationAware
{
    private string _message;
    public string Message
    {
        get { return _message; }
        set { SetProperty( ref _message, value ); }
    }

    public void OnNavigatedTo( NavigationParameters parameters )
    {
        Message = parameters[ "message" ].ToString();
    }
}
```

Setup your page to implement your interface and create a BindableProperty on the page

```
public class MainPage : ContentPage, IMyPage
{
    public static readonly BindableProperty MessageProperty = BindableProperty.Create( nameof( Message ), typeof( string ), typeof( MainPage ), string.Empty );

    public string Message
    {
        get { return (string)GetProperty( MessageProperty ); }
        set { SetProperty( MessageProperty, value ); }
    }
}
```

In the Xaml markup bind the property from your ViewModel to the Bindable Property

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" 
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="MyApplication.Views.MainPage"
             Message="{Binding Message}">
</ContentPage>
```

Finally in your renderer handle changes to the property

```
public class MyPageRenderer : PageRenderer
{
   protected override void OnElementChanged( VisualElementChangedEventArgs e )
    {
        base.OnElementChanged( e );
        // Do foo
    }
}
```

Mind you a better way is to just implement this on one base page type that you make your pages inherit from instead of ContentPage or TabbedPage, etc and then checking to see if you page implemented the interface.

2) Use the IEventAggregator to listen for and handle an event.

```
public class MainPageViewModel : INavigationAware
{
    IEventAggregator _ea { get; }
    public MainPageViewModel( IEventAggregator ea )
    {
        _ea = ea;
    }

    public void OnNavigatedTo( NavigationParameters parameters )
    {
        _ea.GetEvent<MyEvent>().Publish( parameters[ "message" ].ToString() );
    }
}

public class MyPageRenderer : PageRenderer
{
    public MyPageRenderer()
    {
        var ea = ( App as PrismApplication ).Container.Resolve<IEventAggregator>();
        ea.GetEvent<MyEvent>().Subscribe( OnMyEvent );
    }

    public void OnMyEvent( string message )
    {
        // Do what you need to
    }
}
```

EDIT:
If you require something be set on initialization, remember you can access the Container from your Renderer and inject an Interface or Concrete type to access the property or properties you require. I'll use Unity as an example. This makes the code far more testable than to use static properties.

```
public class App : PrismApplication
{
    protected override void RegisterTypes()
    {
        Container.Register<IMySettings,MySettings>( new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager() );
    }
}

public class MyPageViewModel
{
    IMySettings _mySettings { get; }

    public MyPageViewModel( INavigationService navigationService, IMySettings mySettings )
    {
        _mySettings = mySettings;
        // Update this somewhere in the code before navigating to the new page
    }
}

public class MyPageRenderer : PageRenderer
{
    public MyPageRenderer()
    {
        var mySettings = ( App as PrismApplication ).Container.Resolve<IMySettings>();
        // Use MySettings to set the property you need to set
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the ideas! I already solved my problem using static property, that already exist on 3rd party library i am using.
Your solutions may not work as PageRenderer initiated before OnNavigatedTo happen. 
+1 for details and samples